# Possible to apply a Shadow to an entire Group with VBA (but not to GroupItems)?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a PowerPoint VBA script to apply some default styles to selected objects, and I'm running into some problems with grouped objects. Essentially, if I apply `ShadowFormat` adjustments to a Shape group, the shadow is applied to the items *within* the group rather than to the group itself.

In the example below, the white box, blue box, and blue circle are all grouped. Using the GUI to set a shadow on the group results in just the bounding shape to receive the shadow (i.e., the blue objects don't get a shadow). When applying the shadow via a VB script, however, the shadow is applied to **all three objects individually**, which is not the desired behavior. Inspecting the group with the Format Palette verifies that no shadow is applied to the group directly.

[Image: Shadows on groups problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7LVp.jpg) *(Sorry for the link, I don't have enough rep to post images yet...)*

Here's a code snippet. In this example, the Group in question is the first item on the slide:

```vb
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
With myDocument.Shapes(1).Shadow
  .Visible = True
  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  .Blur = 12
  .Transparency = 0.4
  .OffsetX = 0
  .OffsetY = 3
  .Obscured = msoTrue
End With
```

I expect the shadow to only be applied to the group, as it is when you use the GUI to apply a shadow to a group. Instead, all of the group's sub-shapes have their shadows set, and the group *itself* does not receive a shadow.

Comment: I'll bet your dollars to donuts you should be using the ShapeRange object.  I've never worked with PowerPoint in VBA so I don't have experience to back this but the object model points that direction.  Here's some reading for you.  [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/powerpoint/how-to/work-with-shapes-drawing-objects) and some more [ShapeRange.Shadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.shadow)

Comment: Thanks, @ProfoundlyOblivious. I was hoping that you were onto something, but unfortunately, applying the shadow to the ShapeRange didn't do the trick. Exact same result as before.

Comment: Awe, dangit! That's what I get for opening my big mouth. I'll poke around the object model a bit more, your solution is in there.  Somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow is a property of a shape. A group is not a shape. So shadows can only be applied to the members of the group, not the group itself.

To get this effect, copy all shapes, make an array out of them, merge them using the MergeShapes method, send the merged shape to the back and apply a shadow to it. Here's how to use MergeShapes, thanks to Shyam Pillai for this:

```
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape
Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Call ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition)).MergeShapes(msoMergeCombine)
```

Comment: Hi John, The [MergeShapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.mergeshapes) method isn't what I'm looking for. It's a boolean logic operation that is destructive.

And a Group actually _is_ a Shape (see the [ShapeRange.Group Method Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.group#remarks)). If I set the group shadow via the GUI, I can query the Shadow property on the Group shape.

Comment: I am well aware the MergeShapes is destructive. That's why I mentioned _copying_ the shapes first. After you merge all shapes, then move the new shape to the back, applying a shadow will then show only the shadow of the group, not any shadows from submembers.

Comment: I appreciate that your approach would technically work, but it's completely unworkable for what I'm trying to do. What I need is a way to trigger the effect that is created when the Format Palette GUI is used.

I suspect that there is either a bug in the COM object API, or there's some other obscure reason why it won't work the way I'm looking for. There have been a number of inconsistencies with coded vs GUI implementations of features...